# Long click does not work for parent layout, if the child view is a TextView with autoLink=web and linksClickable=true

Tags: android

I have an item of recyclerView, this view contains a ViewGroup and its child TextView with `linksClickable=true` and `autoLink=web`. The value of textview sometimes is plain text sometimes text with the link, when it contains only plain text `longClick` on its parent Layout (**wrapper_layout_id**) works perfectly, but when it contains some links `longClick` doesn't call.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/wrapper_layout_id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/child_text_id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:linksClickable="true"
android:autoLink="web|email"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't understand why it is such a big deal :/ I just want longClick for its parent